# Can read length delimited file in Julia but not in Rust

Tags: c#, rust, julia

In julia I am able to read the first 4 bytes from the file using this code.  (It is the length of the message to read)

```
  # Read the length in first 4 bytes
  msglen = read(R.buffer, UInt32)

  # Then read up to that length
  bytes = read(R.buffer, msglen)
```

But when I try to read the same file in Rust the length value comes up way too big:

```
    let mut f = std::fs::File::open("../20181002.bytes").unwrap();
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    f.read_to_end(&mut buf).expect("file reading failed");
 

    let mut dst = [0u8; 4];
    let mut read_index = 0usize;

    // select first 4 bytes of buf and clone into dst
    dst.clone_from_slice(&buf[read_index..(read_index+4)]);
    println!("Dst: {:?}", &buf[read_index..(read_index+4)]);

    let length = u32::from_le_bytes(dst);
    println!("Len: {}", length);
```

```
Dst: [31, 139, 8, 0]
Len: 559903

I think the first 4 bytes should be 1f8b 0800 0000 0000
```

If its of help, here is how its written in C#:

```
        public static void Write(Stream stream, byte[] bytes)
        {
            var lengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(bytes.Length);

            // Write object length.
            stream.Write(lengthBuffer, offset: 0, count: 4);

            // Write object.
            stream.Write(bytes, offset: 0, count: bytes.Length);
        }
```

Comment: What's the expected length of the message? or what's the shape of the message?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with endianess. Have you tried `u32::from_be_bytes()` already?

Comment: *"I think the first 4 bytes should be 1f8b 0800 0000 0000"* - that's 8 bytes, but anyway the first 4 are identical to `[31, 139, 8, 0]`. The former is formatted in hexadecimal while the latter is in decimal, its the same data though.

Comment: I tried be bytes.  Could it be my C# write method is messed up?

Comment: What is the expected number?

Comment: Is one of those correct: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3ba337307f98a4d5039032bd8f16392

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride No.

Comment: So sorry guys, this is happening because the file is gzip encoded.

Comment: If I do `read(IOBuffer(UInt8[31, 139, 8, 0]), UInt32) |> Int`, I get the same 559903 value that Rust gives. What value does Julia give for you? Also, are you running these on the same computer, just to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1f8b  is the magic number for gzip encoded files.